# Django - id null - foreign key error

Tags: sql, django, python-2.7, django-forms

Error:

```
app_a.desc_id may not be NULL
```

I believe my problem is I'm not passing the `id` from `formB` to `formA` when I save. please please lead me to a solution for this problem.

Here's my view:

```
def form(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formB = BForm()
        formA = AForm()
        return render(request,r'app/form.html',{'formA':formA,'formB':formB})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formA = AForm(request.POST)
        formB = BForm(request.POST)
        formB.save()
        formA.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/log')
```

Here are my models:

```
# Descprition
class B(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

# Title
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField('Name',max_length=20)
    desc = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

and here is my form:

```
class BForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ['description']

class AForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ['name']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has multiple errors but the main problem for this is because `desc` is a foreign key in `class A` that points to `class B`, and you don't have `null=True` on it, meaning you never want that field to be empty. In other words, each instance of `A` should have a foreign key `desc`.

If you just `save()` both forms, `formA` tries to save an instance of `A`, without having a value for `desc` field, hence the error. You should assign the instance that `formB` creates to the instance that `formA` creates:

```
new_b = formB.save()
new_a = formA.save(commit=False)
new_a.desc = new_b
new_a.save()
```

Other problems in your program including never called `form.is_valid()`, having redundant `id` fields(django would create one for you). I suggest you read django tutorial first before jumping into coding. It would save a lot of time like figuring out errors like this.